# select multiple options in listbox edge browser ruby selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, microsoft-edge

There is one requirement for my application to select multiple items from a listbox in microsoft edge browser

I am using watir webdriver to test my application

The DOM structure is as follows:

```
<div id="textSearch">
<div id="textSearch">
<select name="@Type" id="textType" onchange="unselectOptionZero('@Type');" size="7" multiple="" width="250">
<option value="*" selected="">- All -</option>
<option value="text1">text1</option>
<option value="text2">text2</option>
<option value="text3">text3</option>
<option value="text4">text4</option>
<option value="text5">text5</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried these following command to select multiple values

```
@browser.select_list(:id, "textType").option(:value => "text3").select
@browser.send_keys :control
@browser.select_list(:id, "textType").option(:value => "text4").select
```

which does not seem to working. I tried using iteration via .select but it does not seem to be working.

I also tried selenium support **Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new** but it does not help. Is there any other way to select multiple options in microsoft edge browser using **execute_script** using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watir's `Select#select` selects the options by calling the `#click` method. Unlike other drivers, Edge treats this like a regular click, which unselects the previous options. This is a [known/expected behaviour](https://developer.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5437605/) by the Microsoft Edge Team.

Their suggestion is to use the Actions object to press and hold the control button. However, attempting to do this, ex by calling `option.click(:control)`, will result in an unknown command exception. The Edge driver has [not yet implemented the Actions command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-commands).

Until then, you will need to execute JavaScript to select the options.

If you are using Watir v6.8 or later, you can use the new `#select!` method to select the option via JavaScript instead of mouse clicks. This will retain the previously selected values.

```
s= @browser.select_list(:id, "textType")
s.select!("text3")
s.select!("text4")
```

Note that `#select` now supports looking for options by both text and value (as opposed to prior versions where it only checked text).

If you are using earlier versions of Watir, the same can be done using `#execute_script`:

```
s= @browser.select_list(:id, "textType")
select_script = 'arguments[0].selected=true;'
@browser.execute_script(select_script, s.option(:value => "text3"))
@browser.execute_script(select_script, s.option(:value => "text4"))
```